# diff showing difference when there is none

Tags: linux, diff

These two files show as different when compared with

```
diff d_out.txt D_out.txt
```

I'm using Ubuntu (12.10) terminal.

The content of d_out.txt

```
ABCADBACDABCADBACDAB
ABCABCABCABCABCABCAB
CRASH
CRASH
CRASH
ABCDCABADCDBABCDCABA
ABCDBACBDABCDBACBDAB
ABCCABBCAABCCABBCAAB
ABCDDCBAABCDDCBAABCD
CRASH
CRASH
ABCDEEDABCCBEDAADCBE
ABCCAABCCAABCCAABCCA
ABBCCABBCCABBCCABBCC
ABCDEFFABCDEEFABCDDE
AABCDEFFABCDEEFABCDD
ABBCDEFAABCDEFFABCDE
ABBCCDDEDDCCBBABBCCD
CRASH
CRASH
ABCDEFGBADCFEBGDAFCB
ABCDEBADCBEDABCDEBAD
ABCDBADCABCDBADCABCD
ABCDEFGHIABCDEFGHIAB
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHI
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSA
CRASH
AABBCCDCCBBAAEAABBCC
AABBCCDCCBBAAEAABBCC
```

The contents of D_out.txt

```
ABCADBACDABCADBACDAB
ABCABCABCABCABCABCAB
CRASH
CRASH
CRASH
ABCDCABADCDBABCDCABA
ABCDBACBDABCDBACBDAB
ABCCABBCAABCCABBCAAB
ABCDDCBAABCDDCBAABCD
CRASH
CRASH
ABCDEEDABCCBEDAADCBE
ABCCAABCCAABCCAABCCA
ABBCCABBCCABBCCABBCC
ABCDEFFABCDEEFABCDDE
AABCDEFFABCDEEFABCDD
ABBCDEFAABCDEFFABCDE
ABBCCDDEDDCCBBABBCCD
CRASH
CRASH
ABCDEFGBADCFEBGDAFCB
ABCDEBADCBEDABCDEBAD
ABCDBADCABCDBADCABCD
ABCDEFGHIABCDEFGHIAB
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHI
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSA
CRASH
AABBCCDCCBBAAEAABBCC
AABBCCDCCBBAAEAABBCC
```

The text is originally from a program that was done to solve a contest problem. The D_out.txt file is the original judge output and d_out.txt is my output from the program that I've coded to solve that problem. I tried to find small differences but got none.

Comment: put here output of `diff d_out.txt D_out.txt`

Comment: This looks like a newline difference problem -- have you tried using `dos2unix` on both files and compute the difference on such altered files?

Comment: no difference between both files here; run with diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2

Comment: try using diff -Bby d_out.txt D_out.txt

Comment: I agree with Rubens. Check for whitespaces or other hidden characters in your files! (use `od -x d_out.txt > d_out.hex` etc, and `diff *.hex` files)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These texts are equal.

What does `diff` outputs? you might have some extra white spaces there.

try

`diff -w -B d_out.txt D_out.txt`

`-w` Ignore all white space.

`-B` Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

Check out the different [diff options](http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try using vimdiff. It will highlight any possible difference on trailing spaces.

Comment: `vimdiff file1 file2`. Only answer that helped me. Thanks